# Setting xtick formatter on seaborn catplot changes the value of the x ticks to the index

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to visualize a simple order book dataframe with a seaborn catplot. However, when I set the format of the x tick labels of the ax of the catplot, it changes the values of the labels to being the index (0-10 instead of 9.95-10.05). I've tried using a .barplot() directly and the same result happens. Is this something in how seaborn creates bar charts? I have never had this issue with line charts.

```
book = pd.DataFrame({'price': np.arange(10.05, 9.95, -0.01), 'type': '?', 'qty': 0})
book.iloc[1, 2] = 1800
book.iloc[2, 2] = 500
book.iloc[3, 2] = 500
book.iloc[4, 2] = 100
book.iloc[0:6, 1] = 'Ask'

book.iloc[6, 2] = 100
book.iloc[7, 2] = 200
book.iloc[8, 2] = 600
book.iloc[9, 2] = 2500
book.iloc[6:11, 1] = 'Bid'

cat = sns.catplot(x='price', y='qty', data=book, hue='type', kind='bar') 
cat.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
```

[image: plot]

```
cat.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: f'{x:.2f}'))
```

[image]

Comment: Not my bread&butter, but something *like* `lambda x, pos: f'{book["price"][x]:.2f}')`  ??

Comment: Possibly `lambda x, pos: f'{book.price.iloc[x]:.2f}')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Python seaborn categorical barplot with custom formatted x-axis tick labels

You need to convert from the integer x-axis indices back to the corresponding `price` values in the dataframe.

For example, like so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


book = pd.DataFrame(
    {"price": np.arange(9.95, 10.05, 0.01), "type": "?", "qty": 0}
)
book.iloc[1, 2] = 1800
book.iloc[2, 2] = 500
book.iloc[3, 2] = 500
book.iloc[4, 2] = 100
book.iloc[0:6, 1] = "Ask"

book.iloc[6, 2] = 100
book.iloc[7, 2] = 200
book.iloc[8, 2] = 600
book.iloc[9, 2] = 2500
book.iloc[6:11, 1] = "Bid"


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=150)
sns.barplot(
    x="price",
    y="qty",
    data=book,
    hue="type",
    ax=ax,
    order=book["price"][::-1],
    dodge=False,
)

ax.set_xticks(range(len(book["price"])))
ax.set_xticklabels(book["price"].round(2), rotation=45)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: f'${book["price"].iloc[x]:.2f}')
)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Python seaborn categorical barplot with custom formatted x-axis tick labels]

> <sub>***Note***: I'm not 100% sure if there is an error in the sample code you provide or not, but, oddly, it was necessary to change the prices range (defined with `np.arange`) and yet then reverse the order of the plotted data to obtain a plot that matched the expected output provided and shown in question.</sub>